# Initializing cannot convert from const char [3] to std::string *

Tags: c++, string, function, pointers, error-handling

i'm working on a program that uses a function and pointers to replace commas with spaces after a user inputs a sentence.

However when I run the program I receive the above error and another that says;

"C++ a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "std::string *""

having trouble with this program and wondering if anyone here can give me a nudge in the right direction?

Thank you!

Heres the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;




 void comma2blank(string* pString1);
 int main()

{

string* String1 = "  " ;

    cout << "Tell me why you like programming" << endl;
    getline(cin, *String1);

    comma2blank(String1);
    cout << " String 1 without comma is: " << *String1 << endl;

    delete String1;
    system("pause");

 };


 void comma2blank(string* pString1)
 {

pString1->replace(pString1->find(','), 1, 1, ' ');
pString1->replace(pString1->find(','), 1, 1, ' ');



 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a string pointer in your `main()`. You need a full string object and you can pass its address (a pointer) to your function like this:

```
int main()
{
    string String1; // NOT a pointer!

    cout << "Tell me why you like programming" << endl;
    getline(cin, String1);

    comma2blank(&String1); // NOTE: pass by pointer using & (address of)
    cout << " String 1 without comma is: " << String1 << endl;

    // no need to delete anything here

    system("pause");    
};
```

Comment: Bless you dude, really appreciate the help. I'm new to coding so sorry for the novice question.  Thanks again!